# What is the Journalism tag used for?

Tags: discussion, support, tagging

What is the [journalism](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journalism) tag for?

I have a piece of journalism I want to write, and want advice, but I don't know where to do it.

Comment: Writing advice is generally outside the scope of this site, unless it concerns some very specific, narrow problem. The tag has not been used much, so there is no well established practice its use; it was probably intended for the questions that seek analysis of the vocabulary and syntax of English used in journalism, in so far as they are different from what can be seen in other settings (i.e. the questions about what is sometimes referred to as 'journalese').

Comment: @jsw I think that's an answer.

Comment: Plus all tags on this group are faulty and contradictory and randomly applied, by new users who have no idea what they're supposed to mean. I never pay any attention to them, and gods know I wish no one else did, either. Totally useless, imo.

Comment: Tags aren't perfect but imagine you've a question about the word "the" or genitive "'s" or any other common English word or morpheme. Searching for "the" or "s" won't get you far. (Admittedly part of the problem is it's not clear how to add or remove a tag, or who should be doing this.)

Comment: Given the variety of terminology used there, and the anxious cluelessness of the students who ask questions here, there's not a prayer they could find out what they want to know, because they always ask about something else that doesn't quite fit and they don't know why. You can't search for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going through most of the questions in that tag, they fall into a few groups:

**Terms used by journalists/terms related to journalism:**

- [Is there a word that describes when an editor sends some copy back to be altered?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333474/is-there-a-word-that-describes-when-an-editor-sends-some-copy-back-to-be-altered)
- [The meaning of "did not immediately respond to requests for comment"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186272/the-meaning-of-did-not-immediately-respond-to-requests-for-comment)
- [Journalistic term for front-page promotional strip](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/340485/journalistic-term-for-front-page-promotional-strip)
- [Term a 'sheet something' to prove you are a published journalist/writer?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/367689/term-a-sheet-something-to-prove-you-are-a-published-journalist-writer)
- [Wolﬀ ’s sweetening the beat](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/426115)
- [The proper name for a “story with photos”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/462143/the-proper-name-for-a-story-with-photos)
- [Is there a word for a question asked despite knowing the answer, but meant to elicit a response for the sake of the audience?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/417054/is-there-a-word-for-a-question-asked-despite-knowing-the-answer-but-meant-to-el)
- [Origin of the interjection "shock horror"!](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/448378/origin-of-the-interjection-shock-horror)

**Phenomena seen in print**:

- [Conventions of abbreviations of pages (pp.), for academic/journal purposes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389598/conventions-of-abbreviations-of-pages-pp-for-academic-journal-purposes)
- [Strange Omission of "to be" in The Onion Headlines](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/411520/strange-omission-of-to-be-in-the-onion-headlines)
- [The origin of the current use of 'readout' in reporting political news](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/431725/the-origin-of-the-current-use-of-readout-in-reporting-political-news)
- [Origins of the 'editorial we' and its counterpart, the 'editorial I'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/451821/origins-of-the-editorial-we-and-its-counterpart-the-editorial-i)
- [Media writing: beginning sentences with coordinating conjunctions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/469217/media-writing-beginning-sentences-with-coordinating-conjunctions)
- [Journalese verb tenses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/527444/journalese-verb-tenses)

**Random tagging**, occasionally from an OP who found the term in a newspaper:

- [Why represent percentages with "pc" rather than "%"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/607519/why-represent-percentages-with-pc-rather-than)
- [Is there a name for separating two items with comma when listing them?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/587687/is-there-a-name-for-separating-two-items-with-comma-when-listing-them)
- [How can I attribute an entire paragraph to a source?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/540971/how-can-i-attribute-an-entire-paragraph-to-a-source)
- [What are the differences between practical implications, insightful implications, and limitations of a research study?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/534276/what-are-the-differences-between-practical-implications-insightful-implications)
- ["Prop up the table"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/530313/prop-up-the-table)
- [Are there any style guides that dictate the use of "on/at Amazon" (and other web platforms). If so, what are they and what's the reasoning behind it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/404916/are-there-any-style-guides-that-dictate-the-use-of-on-at-amazon-and-other-web)
- [What does DLRS Mean as the 4th Most Common Word in ~10,000 News Articles?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/340140/what-does-dlrs-mean-as-the-4th-most-common-word-in-10-000-news-articles)
- [What is the origin of "pratfall?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/379870/what-is-the-origin-of-pratfall)
- [What effect is the writer trying to create with the use of "bigly?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/379873/what-effect-is-the-writer-trying-to-create-with-the-use-of-bigly)

---

As to your question about asking for advice, @[jsw29](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/282363/jsw29) [wrote in a comment](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15631/what-is-the-journalism-tag-used-for?cb=1#comment63808_15631)

> Writing advice is generally outside the scope of this site, unless it concerns some very specific, narrow problem. The tag has not been used much, so there is no well-established practice its use; it was probably intended for the questions that seek analysis of the vocabulary and syntax of English used in journalism, in so far as they are different from what can be seen in other settings (i.e. the questions about what is sometimes referred to as 'journalese').

If your question is more about creating an effect or writing journalism in general, and less about the *English Language*, I suggest posting on [Writing.SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) as an alternative. They also have a [[Journalism]](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journalism) tag, for which the excerpt reads:

> This tag should be used for questions about writing practices relating to journalism, such as style guides, ethics and ways to publish.

If your question falls under that scope, it's far likelier to be on-topic there than it is here.